# SpriteKit SKNodes position value is changing 64 bit CGFloat to 32 bit

Tags: swift, sprite-kit, cgpoint

I am having an issue with my SKShapeNode and SKCameraNode changing from a 64bit value to 32bit. I need very specific values otherwise my SKCameraNode will start to become jittery when I move in too much. The value changes when I calculate a position and set it to the objects position value.

```
func updatePos(delta:CGFloat, ct:CGFloat){

    let t = ct.truncatingRemainder(dividingBy: T)
    let newPos = getPos(at: t)

    prevPos = self.position
    self.position = newPos
    self.vel = calcVel()

    if(self.objectName == "Earth"){
        print("P1: \(newPos.dictionaryRepresentation)")
        print("P2: \(self.position.dictionaryRepresentation)")
    }

}
```

Examples of what values it will print:

```
P1: {
   X = "1509021.166536532";
   Y = "188778.6327918158";
}
P2:   {
   X = "1509021.125";
   Y = "188778.625";
}

P1: {
   X = "1509021.16715277";
   Y = "188778.6279487592";
}
P2: {
   X = "1509021.125";
   Y = "188778.625";
}
```

I've tried using SKActions to move the nodes but it still makes no difference.

Is there any way I can prevent the numbers from changing?